# in .NET, How do I set STAThread when I'm running a form in an additional thread?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, com

I'm running a form in a second thread.  If I do Ctrl-C to copy text on the clipboard, I get an Exception, "Current thread must be set to a single thread apartment (STA) before OLE calls can be made.   (Using the clipboard involves OLE apparently).

Putting the [STAThread] with my thread proc, which is the entry point of my second thread does *NOT* work.  What will work?

```
[STAThread]
private void MyFormThreadproc(object o)
{
    form = new MyForm();
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create the thread, call the [`SetApartmentState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx) method before you start it. You can't do this for threadpool threads.

For example:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(threadAction);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```