# Running into a .NET COMException with MS Office Interop

Tags: asp.net, com, interop, ms-office, clipboard

I am trying to work with the Windows clipboard and Office Interop in an ASP.NET web application.

Everything works well on my local machine running XP (i have created a Windows application first which ran perfectly well on local machine). Then I have executed it on a server running Windows Server 2003 and it worked there as well.

Then I made a ASP.NET sample project and it worked on my local machine. However when this time I deployed it at the server, after banging my head with permissions, it started giving me this exception which i have no idea why it is doing this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80048240): 
Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or 
contains data which may not be pasted here. 
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shapes.Paste()
```

Is the problem with any sort of permissions again on clipboard? If yes, how can I grant appropriate permissions?

I need to copy the exact chart and I am just using example from MSDN website.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but this article about [using the `Clipboard` class in ASP.NET](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/community-forums/interesting-resources/using-clipboard-class-in-asp-net.aspx) says that you might need to manually change the `ApartmentState` for the active thread to  `STA`, to be able to use the clipboard in ASP.NET.

There are a few questions about this subject on Stackoverflow as well:

- [Clipboard.GetText returns null (empty string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string)
- [in .NET, How do I set STAThread when I’m running a form in an additional thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798761/in-net-how-do-i-set-stathread-when-im-running-a-form-in-an-additional-thread)
- [Using Clipboard.GetDataObject() from a .Net worker thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283368/)